# how can i exclude one content type from drupal search

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

How can i exclude one content type from drupal search. I am using node_quick_find module also for autocomplete search. Is there any way to do the same.
Please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To remove a content type from search you can use the search configuration module. http://drupal.org/project/search_config

It uses permissions to filter out unwanted content types.

Answer (score 2):

Even you can use

http://drupal.org/project/custom_search 
http://drupal.org/project/search_type

modules for this...